# Identifying Crystal Resonator Case Marking ('T' in a Diamond)

Tags: identification, crystal

I have been trying for several hours to identify the manufacturer of a quartz resonator.  There is a marking of a 'T' in a rhombus, like so:

[image]

Does anybody know who's mark this is?  I know that I've seen it before, but none of the lists that have come up on any of my searches contain this logo.  I also tried performing a Google image search with this drawing (and a few variations) without result.

Comment: Crystals are pretty much a commodity-- if this isn't a major manufacturer (and I don't think it is) there are literally hundreds of Chinese factories making such things. Seems like a lot of work to locate a specific one.

Comment: Here is a good place to start http://www.alldatasheet.com/manufacturer/a.jsp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Taiwan-based quartz frequency control component manufacturer "TAITIEN ELECTRONICS CO.,LTD" has a very similar logo. Link to the English version of their website is below.

http://www.taitien.com.tw/en/index.aspx

Comment: wow...tbh i thought that i would never find out.  i've since gotten what i needed without that information, but i'm impressed, and it's nice to know for future reference!